# Does MongoDB support optional filters?

Tags: mongodb

I have a case where I want to run a query that MUST match some field conditions but SHOULD match some others. If they don’t match however the query should still return the conditions that MUST.

For example let’s say in a collection I have 3 documents such as:

```
{ _id: 1, position: “Developer”, name: “Greg”, surname: “Smith” },
{ _id: 2, position: “QA”, name: “Andrew”, surname: “Samson” },
{ _id: 3, position: “Developer”, name: “Adam”, surname: “Mount” }
```

If I run a query with a condition `{ position: “Developer” }` that is a MUST and `{ name: “Greg” }` that is a SHOULD I should just get the record:

```
{ _id: 1, position: “Developer”, name: “Greg”, surname: “Smith” }
```

However, if I run the query again with `{ position: “Developer” }` and `{ “name”: “Daniel” }`, I should get all records that match the MUST condition, therefore **I don't want the `position` condition to fail the query if it doesn't match**. So return records:

```
{ _id: 1, position: “Developer”, name: “Greg”, surname: “Smith” },
{ _id: 3, position: “Developer”, name: “Adam”, surname: “Mount” }
```

Furthermore, if I have a query with MUST conditon `{ position: “Developer” }` and SHOULD conditions `{ name: “Greg”, surname: “Garbrandt” }` I should still get:

```
{ _id: 1, position: “Developer”, name: “Greg”, surname: “Smith” }
```

Not sure if there is a way to write the query to work like this or if there is a functionality that could do this outright.

Comment: What do you mean by "should condition"? Do you like `{ name: “Greg” }` to be displayed or not?

Comment: Should be optional. If it matches any records in the collection it should only return the collections matching this condition along with the `position` condition. If it doesn't however the query should still return all documents matching the `position` condition. So the query shouldn't return nothing if the SHOULD condition fail to match

Comment: i think you need 2 queries, one to try to match all conditions, and if empty to send with few conditions, your condition requires a query to run and return results, its condition based on the collection, not condition based on one document.

Comment: @Takis yes this is what I am trying to avoid I know I can do it with two queries but I don't want to do that I want to see if I can keep it all in one. Also can just run query with the conditions that SHOULD match then filter the rest on my own but that's less efficient

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one:

```
var name = "Daniel";

db.collection.aggregate([
   { $match: { position: "Developer" } },
   {
      $match: {
         $expr: {
            $cond: {
               if: db.collection.findOne({ position: "Developer", name: name }),
               then: { $eq: ["$name", name] },
               else: true
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Or this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $match: { position: "Developer" } },
   { $group: { _id: null, data: { $push: "$$ROOT" } } },
   { $set: { cond: { $filter: { input: "$data", cond: { $eq: ["$$this.name", "Daniel"] } } } } },
   {
      $project: {
         data: {
            $cond: {
               if: { $eq: ["$cond", []] },
               then: "$data",
               else: "$cond"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $unwind: "$data" },
   { $replaceWith: "$data" }
])
```

Comment: This would work but I need something that would work in case of multiple optional conditions like in the third example. I don't think this would work as I would keep have to be adding possible combinations of these filters in a pipeline

Comment: Why? Instead of `cond: { $eq: ["$$this.name", "Daniel"] }` you can put anything else.